# language settings in psiphon pro in android

Tags: security, android, malware, socks-proxy

I have installed psiphon pro apk on my mobile it worked fine in English.
Some thing went wrong and I see all app is in Arabic. I do not understand it is my mobile phone hacked

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. To go back to English, click the second option from the left. Then, click the first option in the middle from the right. Then, click on the first option from the top. English should be an option in it. That is how you change the language back.

Comment: Some screenshots will help.

Comment: that probably is giving flags with country names in left but I think that is to choose best route available not language preference.